# Which actress accrued the most TV screen time as Catwoman?

Tags: dc, batman, actors, batman-1966, catwoman

In the TV series *Batman*, which actress had the most screentime as Catwoman, Julie Newmar, Eartha Kitt, or Lee Meriweather?

Comment: Since this question was originally asked and answered in 2012, Camren Bicondova has now appeared as Selina Kyle in at least 50 episodes of the TV show *Gotham*. Not quite the same question, but an interesting related point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three actresses are seen playing the role of Catwoman during the run of the [Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%28TV_series%29) television series during the 1966 to 1968 which produced 120 episodes. Catwoman appears in 15 of them.

[Julie Newmar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julie_Newmar) rules the roost as the Batman television series most seen Catwoman. She appears in 12 episodes during the first and second seasons.

- Appearing in the premiere Catwoman episodes: Episodes #19 - "The Purr-fect Crime" and episode #20 - "Better Luck Next Time."

[Eartha Kitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eartha_Kitt), plays Catwoman in the third season for three episodes.

[Lee Meriweather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Meriwether) appears as Catwoman in [Batman the Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%281966_film%29) 1966.

[image: Batman the Movie, 1966 starring Adam West]